# accessing remote cassandra database

Tags: cassandra

I am trying to access remote cassendra database by command:

```
cqlsh xx:x:x:x xxxx
got below error:
Connection error: 
    ('Unable to connect to any servers', 
        {'xx:x:x:x': ConnectionShutdown('Connection to xx:x:x:x was closed',)
        }
    )
```

when I am trying to access localhost I am getting error:

```
command: cqlsh 
error:
Connection error: 
    ('Unable to connect to any servers', 
        {'127.0.0.1': error(111, 
        "Tried connecting to [('127.0.0.1', 9042)]. Last error: Connection refused")}
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check that Cassandra is accessible on the given IP & port that you specify in the command line. If you didn't change default ports, then you can use `cqlsh IP`. If it doesn't work, check that you don't have firewall that doesn't allow traffic to port 9042 on given IP.